# cannot remove OnGlobalLayoutListener() in getChildView

Tags: android, listener, expandablelistview

[image]In the app I am builden there is a listview, actually an expandable listview with sublistems - and there are **TWO CASES** depending on which grouplistitem that is clicked: sometimes there is ONE sublistitem, and sometimes there are TWO sublistitems. And when a groupview that contains ONE sublistitem is clicked a FrameAnimation is activated. And because every views has to be completed before this animation is started I have to implement a listener, actually OnGlobalLayoutListener(). And in the onGlobalLayout-method I remove this listener. So far so good.

But what is the problem then? The problem is that if I scroll this sublistitem that contains the framanimation out of view and the scroll back - and THEN click on another grouplistitem that this time contains TWO subitems the frameanimation is applied on one of this sublistitems. In other word - THE LISTENER IS NOT KILLED, ITS ALIVE!!!! Why?

And I have tried to remove this listener in CASE 2 but I cannot now use the pointer **this**

any explantion why this listener is still alive and hove to remove it?

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final ViewHolder holder;

      if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_subphrase, parent, false);
          holder = new ViewHolder();
          holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label_single);
          holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label_couple);
          holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.single);
          holder.imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.couple);
          convertView.setTag(holder);

      } else {  
          holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }
      final int nChildren = getChildrenCount(groupPosition);


      final View v = convertView;
      switch (nChildren) {
        case 1:
            holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
            holder.imageView2.bringToFront();
            holder.text.setText(null);
            holder.text2.setText(contents[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.man_woman_3);
            //extra(groupPosition, category, holder.text, convertView, parent);
            showThaiImages(groupPosition, holder.text, convertView, parent);
            // Väntar till all layout är avklarad - efter detta bearbetas animering. 

            vto = convertView.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  //vet inte om denna metod är nödvändig
                holder.imageView2.bringToFront();
                holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation3);
                frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) holder.imageView2.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.start();
            }}); 
            break;

        case 2:


            try {
                System.out.println("ViewTreeObserver is alive = : " + vto.isAlive());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            holder.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            holder.imageView.bringToFront();
            holder.text2.setText(null);
            //holder.imageView.invalidate();
            holder.text.setText(contents[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            switch (childPosition) { // Switch-villkor för man eller kvinna. 
                case 0: // Man.
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.man_3);
                    break;
                case 1: // Kvinna.
                    holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.woman_3);
                    break;
            }
            break;
      }

      notifyDataSetChanged();
      return convertView;
  }
```

Comment: I got around this problem by just setting the imageview that is holding the frameanimation to View.GONE , that is holder.imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE); But I all the same would like to know how to remove the listener because its still there. I dont like it

Answer (score 4):

I also encounter similar problem and it is also about expanding listview.
I build an adapter that show list item with animation and support with in-scrollview display.
However, I have problem calculating the height of expanding viewGroup. 
The height of expanding viewGroup is always 0, even in the overridden OnDraw() OnLayout().

In the end, i use the OnGlobalLayoutListener to detect when height is changed.
Also, OnGlobalLayoutListener is never removed, and somehow there is more and more OnGlobalLayoutListener stacking on the same view.

I have think about is the deprecate function stop the listener from being removed.
But I did not help after I change it to :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(View v,
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener listener) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
    } else {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Still looking for a way to remove it....

**edit:**
Just found a possible cause. In my case, the onLayoutListener is also triggered when other listview item is expanded. This may caused by expanding of one listview item make other item to re-layout, and trigger the onLayoutListener as a result.

Actually, onLayoutListener is removed in my case.